# Wordpress Add sub menu inside div of parent li using the Walker_Nav_Menu

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, menu, parent-child

I need a similar work. The parent element will be added to the submenu. But if there are # special elements, there will be no additions. It is very necessary for me. Very happy if you help

```
<ul id="nav">
 <li> <a href="visit_link">Visit</a></li>    
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="visit_link">Visit</a></li>
      <li><a href="sub_link_1">Sub Link 1</a></li>
        </ul>

<li> <a href="#">Visit 2</a></li> 
    <ul class="sub-menu">
       <li><a href="sub_link_2">Sub Link 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="sub_link_3">Sub Link 3</a></li>
            </ul>

 <li><a href="link_3">Visit 3</a></li>
 <li><a href="link_4">Visit 4</a></li>

</ul>
```

I need a similar work. The parent element will be added to the submenu. But if there are # special elements, there will be no additions. It is very necessary for me. Very happy if you help

custom class. Work with it

```
<?php }
    /**
     * WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker class.
     *
     * @extends Walker_Nav_Menu
     */
    class WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
/**
     * What the class handles.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @var string
     *
     * @see Walker::$tree_type
     */

    public $tree_type = array( 'post_type', 'taxonomy', 'custom' );

    /**
     * Database fields to use.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @todo Decouple this.
     * @var array
     *
     * @see Walker::$db_fields
     */
    public $db_fields = array( 'parent' => 'menu_item_parent', 'id' => 'db_id' );

    /**
     * Starts the list before the elements are added.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @see Walker::start_lvl()
     *
     * @param string   $output Used to append additional content (passed by reference).
     * @param int      $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param stdClass $args   An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     */
    public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }
        $indent = str_repeat( $t, $depth );

        // Default class.
        $classes = array( 'sub-menu' );

        /**
         * Filters the CSS class(es) applied to a menu list element.
         *
         * @since 4.8.0
         *
         * @param array    $classes The CSS classes that are applied to the menu `<ul>` element.
         * @param stdClass $args    An object of `wp_nav_menu()` arguments.
         * @param int      $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_submenu_css_class', $classes, $args, $depth ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';
        //$output .= "{$n}{$indent}<ul$class_names>{$n}";
            $output .= "\n$indent<div class='submenu menu-layer secondary'>{$n}";
            $output .= "\n$indent<div class='return-button'>Geri</div>{$n}";
            $output .= "\n$indent<button type='reset' class='close-button' id='menu-button' on='tap:sidebar.toggle'></button>{$n}";
            $output .= "\n$indent<div class='items'>{$n}";

        global $wp_query;

    if( !isset( $this->break_point ) ) {
        $menu_elements = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $args->menu );
        $top_level_elements = 0;

        foreach( $menu_elements as $el ) {
            if( $el->menu_item_parent === '0' ) {
                $top_level_elements++;
            }
        }
        $this->break_point = ceil( $top_level_elements / 2 ) + 1;
     }   



    }

    /**
     * Ends the list of after the elements are added.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @see Walker::end_lvl()
     *
     * @param string   $output Used to append additional content (passed by reference).
     * @param int      $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param stdClass $args   An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     */
    public function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }
        $indent = str_repeat( $t, $depth );
        //$output .= "$indent</ul>{$n}";
          $output .= "$indent</div></div>{$n}";
    }

    /**
     * Starts the element output.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @since 4.4.0 The {@see 'nav_menu_item_args'} filter was added.
     *
     * @see Walker::start_el()
     *
     * @param string   $output Used to append additional content (passed by reference).
     * @param WP_Post  $item   Menu item data object.
     * @param int      $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param stdClass $args   An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     * @param int      $id     Current item ID.
     */
    public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( $t, $depth ) : '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

        /**
         * Filters the arguments for a single nav menu item.
         *
         * @since 4.4.0
         *
         * @param stdClass $args  An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param WP_Post  $item  Menu item data object.
         * @param int      $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $args = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_args', $args, $item, $depth );

        /**
         * Filters the CSS class(es) applied to a menu item's list item element.
         *
         * @since 3.0.0
         * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
         *
         * @param array    $classes The CSS classes that are applied to the menu item's `<li>` element.
         * @param WP_Post  $item    The current menu item.
         * @param stdClass $args    An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param int      $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args, $depth ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        /**
         * Filters the ID applied to a menu item's list item element.
         *
         * @since 3.0.1
         * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
         *
         * @param string   $menu_id The ID that is applied to the menu item's `<li>` element.
         * @param WP_Post  $item    The current menu item.
         * @param stdClass $args    An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param int      $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args, $depth );
        $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        if ( $this->has_children && $depth == 0 ) {
     $output .= $indent . "<label class='menu-item item-layer-1 has-sub-level'>{$n}"; 
        $output .= "<input type='checkbox' class='user-valid valid'>";

     } 

    if ( $this->has_children && $depth == 1 ) {
     $output .= $indent . "<label class='menu-item item-layer-2 has-sub-level'>{$n}"; 
        $output .= "<input type='checkbox' class='user-valid valid'>";

     } 


        //$output .= $indent . '<label' . $id . $class_names .'>';

        $atts = array();
        $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
        $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )     ? $item->target     : '';
        $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? $item->xfn        : '';
        $atts['href']   = ! empty( $item->url )        ? $item->url        : '';

        /**
         * Filters the HTML attributes applied to a menu item's anchor element.
         *
         * @since 3.6.0
         * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
         *
         * @param array $atts {
         *     The HTML attributes applied to the menu item's `<a>` element, empty strings are ignored.
         *
         *     @type string $title  Title attribute.
         *     @type string $target Target attribute.
         *     @type string $rel    The rel attribute.
         *     @type string $href   The href attribute.
         * }
         * @param WP_Post  $item  The current menu item.
         * @param stdClass $args  An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param int      $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args, $depth );

        $attributes = '';
        foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
            if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
                $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
                $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
            }
        }

        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */
        $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );

        /**
         * Filters a menu item's title.
         *
         * @since 4.4.0
         *
         * @param string   $title The menu item's title.
         * @param WP_Post  $item  The current menu item.
         * @param stdClass $args  An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param int      $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $title = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_title', $title, $item, $args, $depth );

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes . ' '. $class_names .'>';
        $item_outputs = $item_output .= $args->link_before . $title . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;



    if ( $this->has_children && $depth == 0 ) {
    $item_output .=$item_outputs;   
    $item_output = $args->before;
    //$item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
    $item_output .= $args->link_before . $title . $args->link_after;
    //$item_output .= '</a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after;  
 } 



 if ( $this->has_children && $depth == 1 ) {

    $item_output = $args->before;
    //$item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'class="menu-item item-layer-2">';
     $item_output .= $args->link_before . $title . $args->link_after;
   // $item_output .= '</a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after;  
  }






        /**
         * Filters a menu item's starting output.
         *
         * The menu item's starting output only includes `$args->before`, the opening `<a>`,
         * the menu item's title, the closing `</a>`, and `$args->after`. Currently, there is
         * no filter for modifying the opening and closing `<li>` for a menu item.
         *
         * @since 3.0.0
         *
         * @param string   $item_output The menu item's starting HTML output.
         * @param WP_Post  $item        Menu item data object.
         * @param int      $depth       Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         * @param stdClass $args        An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         */
        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }




    /**
     * Ends the element output, if needed.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @see Walker::end_el()
     *
     * @param string   $output Used to append additional content (passed by reference).
     * @param WP_Post  $item   Page data object. Not used.
     * @param int      $depth  Depth of page. Not Used.
     * @param stdClass $args   An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     */
    public function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }
        $output .= "</label>{$n}";
    }

}  ?>
```

Comment: you can add submenu as a parent in admin section where you can use custom link with #. and you no need to so custom work

Comment: You're right, but I need this kind of thing. I have a lot of menus and it's very complicated. For Amp version, I need to handle php with Walker_Nav_Menu.